# What should be modified or deleted to replace elementaryOS with Ubuntu 19.04 while retaining Windows?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, uninstall

I want to erase elementary OS completely and install Ubuntu 19.04 
The installer offers me with 2 choices:

- Install alongside (which I don't want).
- Something else (I want to keep windows and install Ubuntu replacing elementary).

What next steps should I do?
Which partitions should I remove/modify?

Here are my partitions:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I haven't used elementary, but I'd use "something else" and just overwrite your elemetnary partitions with Ubuntu ones.  With Ubuntu overwriting Ubuntu, it takes note of additional programs you've added, erases system directories (if you don't format), installs then re-adds back additional programs you added since-install (if you didn't format). Not all elementary programs are likely to be found, but it's what I'd use. Your home directory won't be touched though backup first, and don't select format unless you want to erase what's there...

Comment: I would format elementary partition first after you backup what you want to keep.  Most important is to double check and check again you are using the right partition.  You can leave partition sda6 same size, or you can make a 30GB / partition and make the rest /home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- backup your important Windows files FIRST
- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted`
- delete `/dev/sda6` and `/dev/sda7`
- quit `gparted`
- double-click the "Install Ubuntu" icon on the Desktop
- choose "Install along side of Windows"

Answer (score 0):

Formatting the ext4 partition (or deleting and re-creating it) is sufficient to get rid of Elementary.

Personally I would go a less destructive route: install the ubuntu-desktop package on Elementary (it has Ubuntu under the hood after all), reboot and login to Gnome/Ubuntu. Optionally clean up Elementary repositories and packages after that.